# Edit and Send Outlook Form Template From Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Currently, I have the Excel VBA code that will construct and send an Outlook email from Excel. However, I need to be able to use this VBA to open an Outlook form template that contains a command button and update the body of the message. I have been searching non-stop and cant find any good resources for accomplishing this, any good pointers, links, or supporting code would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How many different templates do you have? This could be accomplished from within Excel, adding the "template" as HTML within your email body... No need to use another button to update the body.

Comment: @Xabier Sorry for not clarifying it as well. the button is for a different task that the receiver of the email would press to update a txt file using Outlook VBA. I just don't know how to call a Outlook form template and update the body

Comment: The message recipient will nto be able to click any buttons in the message body - all scripts in messages are disabled. The recipient would need to install and run your code to have any buttons.

Comment: You can prove the futility with CreateItemFromTemplate https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/application-createitemfromtemplate-method-outlook

Answer (score 0):

You can save the form as a Microsoft Outlook template file (.oft), and then e-mail that file to users. If the form contains code or custom fields, the recipient will not be able to simply open the .oft file and publish it. The recipient will need to save the .oft file to the local drive, run it with the Tools | Forms | Choose Form command, and then publish the form to the Personal Forms Library.

Alternatively, you can use an .fdm file to install a form manually, see [OL2000: How to Move a Custom Form to Another Computer](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=253658).

Read more about Outlook forms in the [To distribute Microsoft Outlook forms to other users](http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=27) article.

As a workaround you may consider creating a COM add-in with rich UI options which can be installed on the recipient's side and do whatever you need for users. See [Walkthrough: Create your first VSTO Add-in for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook) for more information.